# Using POI to extract a worksheet from a spreadsheet

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

We have a need to extract worksheets with a given name, from our spreadsheets, into independent/standalone spreadsheets from a **Java program**.  We are not able to find an easy way to do it.  From an `XSSFWorkbook`object we can get the `XSSFSheet` object by invoking the `getSheet(java.lang.String name)` method but we are finding that:

1. There is no constructor for `XSSFWorkbook` that accepts the `XSSFSheet` as as argument.
2. There is no public method to write `XSSFSheet` to file (which could then have been used as an argument to construct `XSSFWorkbook`)

---

This is a fairly straightforward feature so I feel that there is a simple solution that I am not seeing.

Comment: Open the Workbook, delete all the sheets except the one(s) you want, then save that out?

Comment: What @Gagravarr suggests is the only way in my opinion.
To 1.: There cannot be a such because `XSSFSheet` cannot stand alone. It is at least related to shared strings and styles parts of the workbook. Maybe it also is related to charts, themes, media, ..., which all are parts of the workbook.
To 2: There cannot be a such because `XSSFSheet` cannot stand alone. See 1.